# Using Events in a Python class

Tags: python, websocket

I've got a Python class like so that uses [Events](https://pypi.org/project/Events/).
What I am trying to achieve is so that it's possible to subscribe to an event in the class and make a callback.

```py
class EvoflameAPI:
    """Evoflame api object"""

    def __init__(self, server):
        self._server = server
        self.events = Events()
        return

    def stream(self):
        #websocket.enableTrace(True)
        self.ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(self._server,
                                    on_open=self.on_open,
                                    on_close=self.on_close,
                                    on_message=self.on_message)
        self.ws.run_forever()

    def on_message(self, msg, smth):
        self.events.message(smth)
        #print(smth)
```

I am then calling the class and trying to subscribe to the event like so, however the callback/event never seems to fire:

```py
evoflame = EvoflameAPI('ws://192.168.1.190:81')
evoflame.stream()
evoflame.ws_send('{"voice": "Fire_ON/OFF"}')

def my_callback(msg, smth):
    print("Yay, I got a message!", msg, smth)

evoflame.events.message += my_callback
```

Does anyone know where I'm going wrong?  Printing `smth` in `on_message` logs out the data I am trying to get in the callback

Answer (score 0):

Method `WebSocketApp.run_forever()` is a blocking call, which means that it blocks the `thread` forever. Because of this, your method `EvoflameAPI.stream()` never returns and the callback is never registered since the code below the call doesn't execute. I suggest you to register the callback first and then call `stream()`. But you'll again run into a problem where your method `EvoflameAPI.ws_send()` won't execute. Therefore you need to run your API (or sending method) in a separate `thread` and use some data structure for communication (e.g. `queue.Queue`).

```
evoflame = EvoflameAPI('ws://192.168.1.190:81')

def my_callback(msg, smth):
    print("Yay, I got a message!", msg, smth)

evoflame.events.message += my_callback

evoflame.stream()
```

[Here](https://github.com/websocket-client/websocket-client/blob/master/examples/echoapp_client.py) is a good example from the authors of the library where they start the `WebSocketApp` on the main `thread` and then send messages on a separate `thread`.

Comment: Just updated my question.  I've changed it to the same attribute `events`, however I'm still having the same issue

Comment: @K20GH That was my first thought, but I believe you had another problem. I edited the answer with a new solution.

Comment: So I've added threading and changed the logic which seems to be triggering it.  The issue I now have is `TypeError: my_callback() missing 1 required positional argument: 'msg'`

Comment: @K20GH This is because you are calling the callback with a single parameter `self.events.message(smth)` and the callback you register accepts 2 parameters `my_callback(msg, smth)`.